# how to identify which cell in tableview clicked

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I created `tableview` that read from `url` (any cell has name of book) and when clicked any `cell` gone `detailView`.

in detail view exist `UIScroll` that read any `image` from `url` and I create it.

but my problem this place. I don't know what read images in `UIScroll` related any `cell`.

this is URL : ".../mamal/book.php?**p=%d**&**b=%d**"

(p and b display number page and number book)

I want when clicked first cell (book1) compiler gone next page and display images related book1
and etc.

Comment: DO you want to open page#1 by default? If not, from where you will be passing page # ?

Comment: what you want exactly? not cleared from your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `UITableView` protocols `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>`  in your .h file then use below delegate method which you give which cell is clicked

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked cell-> %d", indexPath.row);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also identify the currently selected row using the property `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

i.e if you want to know the index path of currently selected row at any point of time  without using the delegate methods (not saving it during selection) you can use

```
tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

If you want to pass around the value between multiple view controller you can declare an instance variable in the view controller you want the value to be passed and store `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` in this variable during initialization. A quick search on so should help you with that.